# Wish for vs Wish to

Tags: difference, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between this two prepositional phrase? And how can we use this?
Like

> 1. Best wishes **for** you.
> 2. Best wishes **to** you.

What is the difference in meaning for both of these sentences?

Comment: See this question on our sister site English Language & Usage: [Which one is correct, “best wishes to you” or “best wishes for you”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7771/116151)

Answer (score 1):

> Best wishes for you

Means **I have best wishes** (in my heart / in my soul exc.. ) **for you.**

> Best wishes to you

Means that **I am sending** (to) **you my best wishes**

The most common form is the second one and to be honest, I don't think the first form is used much by Native speakers

Comment: We send good wishes **for** an event in someone's life. "Best wishes for your birthday next week" or, if they are ill, "Best wishes for a speedy recovery."